# ModelState.IsValid is invalid. Why if I can get users created?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

UPDATE: Found what I believe is the cause of the modelState.isValid is false.
The model has 7 properties... and debbuging I found out that model is receiving only 6 properties from a view.

My checkbox is not send to a controller? Is there any extra configurantion I should do to make it happen?

This is the view:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "closeDialog('RegistroUsuario', '<b>Usuário cadastrado com Sucesso!</b>', true)" }, new { id = "FormRegistroUsuario" }))
{
   <fieldset>
        <legend>Cadastro novo Usuário</legend>
       <table id="changePassword">
                <tr>
                    <td class="smallField">Username:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName,new { @class = "validate[required]" }) @Html.ValidationMessage("usernameVal", "*")</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "validate[required]" }) @Html.ValidationMessage("passwordVal", "*")</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Repetir Senha:</td>
                    <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "validate[required,equals[Password]]" }) @Html.ValidationMessage("senhaVal", "*")</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "validate[required,custom[email]]" }) @Html.ValidationMessage("emailVal", "*")</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pergunta Secreta:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecretQuestion, new { @class = "validate[required]" }) @Html.ValidationMessage("secretVal", "*")</td>
                </tr>
                               <tr>
                    <td>Resposta:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecretQuestionPassword, new { @class = "validate[required]" }) @Html.ValidationMessage("awnserVal", "*")</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ativo:</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" value="Ativo" data-val="true"/> @Html.ValidationMessage("activeVal", "*")</td>
                </tr>    
            </table>  
       <input type="submit" value="Criar Usuário" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button-link"/>         
    </fieldset>

}
```

thanks...

---

This is a very strange behavior
I still get the users created for some reason.

Some times users are not created due already existing username. (Even though the user does not exist).. very strange

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            MembershipProvider mp = Membership.Provider;
            MembershipCreateStatus Status;
            string erroMsg;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["status"]))
            {
                model.Active = false;
            }
            else
            {
                model.Active = true;
            }

            MembershipUser newUser = mp.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, model.SecretQuestion, model.SecretQuestionPassword, model.Active, Guid.NewGuid(), out Status);

            try
            {

                if (newUser == null)
                {
                    erroMsg = GetErrorMessage(Status);
                    return Content(erroMsg);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Content("Usuário Cadastrado");
                }

            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new MembershipCreateUserException("An exception occurred creating the user.", e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("isValid is false!");
        }
```

Comment: Hard to tell just with the controller code, Do you use a custom MembershipProvider?

Comment: this is my provider: <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="tgpwebgedString" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the awnser.
The model was really inconsistent. The input checkbox was not been sent to the model thus causing the model.isValid to be false.

I solve the problem using a helper html checkbox.

```
<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Active)</td>
```

All I had to do is to get the checkbox proper value

```
bool checkvalue = bool.Parse(Request.Form.GetValues("Active")[0]);
```

Thanks a lot!